# How to represent specific color for chart in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-online

I need to show appropriate color for every specific value in field.

There was an two fields, **"Account Names"** and **"Range Values"** Range VAlue is an dropdown(Optionset) which contains red,green, gray and blue.

i created chart for displaying account Names related to range values , and got the following chart as shown below.

[image]

Is it possible to show the same colours in chart by choosing the specific colour in form in Dropdown field for particular AccountName.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify exact color options for individual chart item.  For instance you cannot specify that "Third Opportunity" will be purple and "Second Opportunity" blue.

However, you can specify the order of colors that the chart will use, and then sort the chart to correctly match up your colors to your values.  For instance if you know that your charted items are going to be in the order shown above you can specify that the order of colors in your chart be purple, blue, red and then green.

Here is a [great article](https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2012/08/23/palette-custom-colors-in-charts/) by CRM Chart Guy about chart colors.